# Get lowest byte of added values

Tags: c++, gps, byte, checksum

Sorry if this sounds confusing, but I have a GPS nav unit that sends out 72 byte packets via UDP. According to the manual of the GPS, byte 22 of the 72 byte packet is the first checksum to verify the integrity of the packet so far. I have been told that I need to add up the values of the first 21 bytes and compare the lowest byte of that answer with the checksum. If the values match, then the packet is valid so far.

To do this, I wrote C++ code that adds the first 21 bytes

```
checksum = ((unsigned char) buf[0] + (unsigned char) buf[1] + (unsigned char) buf[2] + (unsigned char) buf[3] + (unsigned char) buf[4] + (unsigned char) buf[5] + (unsigned char) buf[6] + (unsigned char) buf[7] + (unsigned char) buf[8] + (unsigned char) buf[9] + (unsigned char) buf[10] + (unsigned char) buf[11] + (unsigned char) buf[12] + (unsigned char) buf[13] + (unsigned char) buf[14] + (unsigned char) buf[15] + (unsigned char) buf[16] + (unsigned char) buf[17] + (unsigned char) buf[18] + (unsigned char) buf[19] + (unsigned char) buf[20] + (unsigned char) buf[21])
```

My question is: how to I get the lowest 8 bits of this so I can compare it with byte 22?

Comment: You can use the bitwise AND operator in C/C++. That operator is `&` . To get the lowest 8 bits you can bitewise `&` the checksum with `0xff`. So you can just add `& 0xff` to the end of your expression (outside the last closing parenthese)

Comment: Thank you! That works great

Comment: Did you consider using a loop to get your checksum? `checksum = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 22; ++i) checksum += (unsigned char) buf[i];`

Comment: thank you john that does seem simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Micheal Petch's comment I just needed to AND the value with 0xff to get the lowest 8 bits.

```
& 0xff;
```